# Сan't install a specific one .inf driver that I need to usb device that i've plugged in

Tags: windows, usb, driver, inf, device-manager

I'm working on a project that uses a microcontroller which can be connected to a PC through USB to manipulate it's functions from virtual machine. I've also have a specific .inf driver for that device from it's manufacturer. However, when I connecting it to a PC Windows device manager displays this device as ["an unknown USB device"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdeYp.png), and installs [a standard usb.inf driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZyMN.png) on it and, as a result, the device doesn't work.

Yes, I tried to update the driver via device manager, added a specific folder with a suitable .inf file and received the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QACjn.png), but I assure you, [it is in the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9Dsu.png). Also tried to install that .inf file on PC using RMB on that file and "install", it says that [everything is ok.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cXPp.png). Then I deleted that USB device from device manager and restart PC, after plugged in it back still getting same thing, windows keep uploading default usb.inf driver for it.
I'm using Windows 11, but tried that on different machines with Windows 7 and Windows 10, same thing on all of them.
I thought that it is a trouble with a driver from manufacturer, but unfortunately this is not the case. He says that it is the only way to use that device and he don't understand why I have that issue, cause all driver files is alright and everything worked properly on their PC's.

The question is: Is there any way to upload exactly .inf file directly to device without windows device manager? (cause in it I only can select a folder with that driver and right after that receive a message that there are no driver...). Maybe I could do it using CMD?

Maybe someone had same issue?